# Create Document Ribbon Not Present

Tags: 2010, document-set

We're running a hosted version of SharePoint Server 2010. It was set up for our company by a consulting firm several years ago and we have had discontinuity in personnel, so a lot of the decision-making process behind certain functionalities have been lost.

I would like to allow for the creation of documents in libraries and manage content types so as to create templates and force folks to create through SharePoint (thus increasing adoption for some project-based tasks). We have Office and Exchange set up and integrated with SharePoint.

One problem: our ribbon has no option for creating documents or document sets--just an option to upload documents or create folders. Is this a customization? The content type 'document set' exists in Site Collection settings, for instance. I figured this ability was something out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have the appropriate content types added to the document library.

Go to the document library > library settings > add from existing site content types > choose your content types, e.g. Document, Document Set > OK.

Comment: Hey submits: 

So I have the content types enabled so they're viewable under the 'new document' button. Everything in that stack should be. I think, however, that someone disabled it programatically. I have read that this can be done through a features XML file, but I haven't been able to find it...

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. In your question you explain your problem being you cannot create new documents - you only have the option of uploading a document or creating a folder. But now you're saying you can now see a "New Document" button. So surely this has answer your question?